# Multiple if conditions in for loop

Tags: c#, datagridview

My application searches through all cells in a datagridview for a particular string and sums the corresponding value in the adjacent cell to a decimal variable. In my code below when i take out the nested if  with the Anotherstring condition, my code runs perfectly. The nested if condition does not run when i insert it into my code. What am i doing wrong?

```
             decimal amount = 0;
             decimal sum = 0;

           foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
           {
            for (int index = 0; index < dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; index++)
                  {

                   DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[index];
                   if (cell.Value == DBNull.Value || cell.Value == null)
                       continue;

                   if (cell.Value.ToString().Contains("String"))
                   {
                       if (cell.Value.ToString().Contains("Anotherstring"))
                       {
                           DataGridViewCell next = row.Cells[index + 1];
                           string s4 = next.Value.ToString();
                           amount += Decimal.Parse(s4, NumberStyles.Currency, custom);

                           textBox50.Text = amount.ToString();

                       }


                       DataGridViewCell nexter = row.Cells[index + 1];
                       string s5 = nexter.Value.ToString();
                       sum += Decimal.Parse(s5, NumberStyles.Currency, custom);

                       textBox41.Text = sum.ToString();

                   }
```

Comment: Are you sure your string contains anotherstring? Is one supposed to be capitalized and one not?

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially get in the inner if statement but Contains is case sensitive.  So you either want to use ToLower or if you do care about case use the proper case in your check.

```
if (cell.Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains("string"))
{
   if (cell.Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains("anotherstring"))
   {
       DataGridViewCell next = row.Cells[index + 1];
       string s4 = next.Value.ToString();
       amount += Decimal.Parse(s4, NumberStyles.Currency, custom);

       textBox50.Text = amount.ToString();

   }


   DataGridViewCell nexter = row.Cells[index + 1];
   string s5 = nexter.Value.ToString();
   sum += Decimal.Parse(s5, NumberStyles.Currency, custom);

   textBox41.Text = sum.ToString();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Contains method is case sensitive.  In your example, "Anotherstring" does not contain "String", so the nested if statement would not be matched.

If you need case insensitive matching, consider using IndexOf().

Comment: Just an FYI.  IndexOf is case sensitive by default.  You have to use IndexOf("string", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)

Comment: I used IndexOf  and it works rather well for me. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, @Gonja.  Would you mind accepting my answer since that's what you used?